# IllegalStateException (Default FirebaseApp is not initialized) in FirebaseInstanceIdService.handleIntent()

Tags: android, firebase

We've started using `Firebase (Analytics, Notifications, Storage, Crashlytics)` recently and now noticed a few crashes in Crashlytics:

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException 
    Default FirebaseApp is not initialized. Make sure to call 
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
    com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance (Unknown Source)
    com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance (Unknown Source)
    com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.zzo (Unknown Source)
    com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.handleIntent (Unknown 
    Source)
    com.google.firebase.iid.zzc.run (Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker 
    (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run 
    (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
```

As far as I can see - this happens somewhere inside `Firebase` lib (i.e. not in our code).

Due to legal requirements, we can't use automatic Firebase initialization (via fake ContentProvider).

We call `FirebaseApp.initializeApp()` in `Application.onCreate()` in most cases, and for some cases (like the first launch, when the user hasn't already accepted license agreement) we call it later.

Our code performs no explicit interactions with Firebase before `initializeApp()` call.

Seems that FirebaseInstanceIdService receives an Intent and tries to do something. 
Do you have any ideas what could possibly go wrong?

Comment: Have you defined any components in your manifest to run in a different process other than the main process?

Comment: Also, have you considered initializing in your own ContentProvider instead of an Application subclass?  Using Application is not recommended by the Android platform team.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.
No, app has no separate processes. 
Never heard about "using application is not recommended". In our case we can't always initialize Firebase right at application start, so I can't see how ContentProvider would help.

Comment: Just for diagnostics, what if you remove Notifications / Cloud Messaging from your app temporarily.  Does that prevent the crash?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible. 
We don't know how to reproduce it, all we have is a couple of Crashlytics\Google Play crash reports.

Comment: Without reproduction steps or some sample code that always exhibits the problem, that makes it really hard to figure out what to do next.